# (Why) should I test if an array is empty prior to a for loop?

Tags: php, if-statement, for-loop

Given an empty array `$items = array();`

Why should I use the following code (which I've seen used before):

```
if (count($items) > 0) {
   foreach ($items as $item) // do stuff here
}
```

instead of just

```
foreach ($items as $item) // do stuff here
```

If `count($items) === 0` the loop won't execute anyway??

Comment: I think the `foreach` throws a NOTICE or WARNING level error if it's assessing something that doesn't exist, so it's really for programmers who like to keep a completely clean error log.

Comment: Shouldn't you only do it when you are not sure whether you have an array or not?

Comment: and the foreach will be executed on blank array and will give the notice

Comment: As long as $items is an array, you don't need to do that count unless you also want to do something on an else such as display a "no records" message or similar.... if $items isn't an array or Travesable object, then you might want to check its datatype first.... but a foreach against an empty array won't give any notice or warning message

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks for the comment-that-would-have-been-an-equally-good-answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't generally need to do the check. I see lots of code with that check, but it's often unnecessary, and I think it's usually due to ignorance on the part of the programmer. A similar pattern that I frequently see is after database queries:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($stmt) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        ...
    }
}
```

This test is also unnecessary; if no rows were found, the first fetch will return `false`, and the loop will stop.

The only case where it's useful is if you want to tell the user that there were no results, instead of just displaying an empty table. So you might do:

```
if (count($items) > 0) {
    echo "<table>";
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // display table row
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "<b>No data found!</b>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for also mentioning the eventual use-case for 'no data found', it's evident but I didn't think of it when I posted the question !

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on what you want to do. As the comments have pointed out, you may want an empty array to be a special case, so you'd like to handle that case differently. Otherwise, no `warning` will be thrown if you execute `foreach` on an empty array, you just won't get any results. A typical check you should execute is if `$items` is an array at all, or cast `$items` into an array anyway to avoid getting that `warning`. If you did that and `$items` would be generally be converted into an array of one value, i.e. the value `$items` had at that point.

e.g.

```
$items = 2;
foreach((array)$items as $item) {
    print $item; //will print 2 alright
  }
```

or

```
if(is_array($items)) {
    foreach($items as $item) {
      print $item;
    }
}
else {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: If `$items` is supposed to be an array and isn't, that's likely to be a bug. The cast will hide the bug, which is usually a bad idea.

Comment: But it depends on what is to be accomplished, that's why the second option is lot more fun.